# Network interface down on boot

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, network-manager

I have recently upgraded my server / nas, with a ASRock H470M-ITX/ac because of the included 2.5GB network interface, i installed the r8125 drivers and got the network interface to show up in `ifconfig -a` as enp3s0, the only issue i'm having is that the interface is down after every reboot, the only way i found for now to get it to work in some way is by running `ifconfig enp3s0 192.168.0.249 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` after which it shows up in my local network but it still fails at something like `ping 8.8.8.8`

I thought after reading the readme included with the driver i might needed to change some config files to configure the interface to show up on boot so i added both `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp3s0` and `etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-enp3s0` with the lines

```
DEVICE=enp3s0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
```

also `/etc/network/interfaces` did not exist yet either so i added it and added the following lines

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

both did absolutely nothing

After this i looked towards the NetworkManager for any issues, i first checked if it was even running by running `systemctl is-active NetworkManager` which returned `active`, then i ran `nmcli` which showed enp3s0 as unmanaged, i then ran `nmcli dev set enp3s0 managed yes` after which the interface still showed up as unmanaged, i then removed the contents of `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf` to remove interface from the unmanaged filter, after restarting the networkmanager it still showed up as unmanaged

So now i'm kind of stuck, i obviously want it to connect the interface on boot and have it have internet access as well but i'm not experienced enough with linux networking to know where to go next, any help would be greatly appriciated!

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04. Some other info about the system i'm using:

```
# neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               root@tim-nas 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.6.0-050600-generic 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 44 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 746 (dpkg), 6 (snap) 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.0.17 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Resolution: 1920x1080 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   CPU: Intel i5-10400 (12) @ 2.901GHz 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   GPU: Intel Device 9bc8 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Memory: 438MiB / 7608MiB 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.                           
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/                            
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

```
# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b53 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc8 (rev 03)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d2
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06ba (rev f0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bb (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0684
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (11) I219-V
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 2263 (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. Device 2263 (rev 03)
```

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` is no longer used. Take a look at documentation for `netplan`. Another point -- controversial -- is that network manager is not the best choice for servers. It is an old Mac application designed for GUI and hacked for linux laptops and is difficult to debug. For server, I would use `networkd`. I'm not these are at your root issue, but this might point you to more up-to-date documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks @Stephen Boston for pointing me in the right direction, the solution was really simple, all i needed to do is to edit `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` (this file might have a different name but generally any file in /etc/netplan should do, i think) and add the network interface after which the file looks like

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

after which ran `netplan generate` and `netplan apply`, the interface now shows up on boot and i have access to the internet